# Makefile not expanding file* wildcard on NFS

Tags: docker, makefile, nfs, macos-high-sierra, vmware-fusion

I have the folowing setup:

- Ubuntu LTS guest
- MacBook Pro running MacOS 10.13.5 (17F77)
- Hypervisor is VMware Fusion Professional Version 8.5.9 (7098239)
- NFS is exported from MacBook host to Ubuntu guest

This is the relevant line from `/etc/exports`:

```
/Users/stephenrasku/w/Edge-Agent -alldirs -mapall=501:20 edgeos-dev
```

I have the following `Makefile`:

```
build:
    ls -l
    ls -l foo*
```

It fails when I run it in my `i386` container on an NFS mount.  I am running a VMware Fusion :

```
$ docker run --rm -t -v /home/stephen/some-nfs-mount:/home/edge registry.gear.ge.com/predix_edge/edge-agent-i386 "cd tmp && make"
Setting uid/gid to 501 501
ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 builduser builduser 26 Sep 25 17:58 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 builduser builduser  0 Sep 25 17:58 bart
-rw-r--r-- 1 builduser builduser  0 Sep 25 17:58 fool
ls -l foo*
ls: cannot access 'foo*': No such file or directory
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

The `i386` container works if I clone the repository onto a native filesystem and bind mount it into the container:

```
$ docker run --rm -t -v /home/stephen/this-directory-is-not-nfs:/home/edge registry.gear.ge.com/predix_edge/edge-agent-i386 "cd tmp && make"
Setting uid/gid to 501 501
ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 builduser builduser 971 Sep 26 14:21 Dockerfile-i386
-rw-rw-r-- 1 builduser builduser  26 Sep 26 15:06 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 builduser builduser   0 Sep 26 14:21 bart
-rw-rw-r-- 1 builduser builduser   0 Sep 26 14:21 fool
ls -l foo*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 builduser builduser 0 Sep 26 14:21 fool
```

And it also works on NFS if I run in an `x86_64` container:

```
$ docker run --rm -t -v /home/stephen/some-nfs-mount:/home/edge registry.gear.ge.com/predix_edge/edge-agent-x86_64 "cd tmp && make"
Setting uid/gid to 501 501
ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 builduser builduser 26 Sep 25 17:58 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 builduser builduser  0 Sep 25 17:58 bart
-rw-r--r-- 1 builduser builduser  0 Sep 25 17:58 fool
ls -l foo*
-rw-r--r-- 1 builduser builduser 0 Sep 25 17:58 fool
```

The `i386` container is `FROM i386/ubuntu:18.04` and the `x86_64` container is `FROM ubuntu:18.04`.

Is there a way to fix this besides "don't use NFS"?

Comment: Dos the same thing happen when you attempt these commands on the command line? If so, then this problem has nothing to do with Make.

Comment: It doesn't happen on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds wildcard function was somehow disabled on your shell for i386 image.

Try `set +o noglob` to enable it for your `registry.gear.ge.com/predix_edge/edge-agent-i386`.

Some trial like follows, just FYI.

```
# set -o noglob
# ls Doc*
ls: cannot access Doc*: No such file or directory
# set +o noglob
# ls Doc*
Dockerfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it:

    set +o noglob && ls -l foo*
    ls: cannot access 'foo*': No such file or directory

Comment: Strange, I tried to reproduce your issues with your new updated `nfs` matter. But I cannot reproduce it, all thing ok on my side even use `nfs`.

Comment: My setting for nfs: `/nfsroot  *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`. My mount: `mount -t nfs -o nolock 10.192.224.45:/nfsroot kkk`. Docker command: `docker run --rm -t -v /root/kkk:/root withmake bash -c "cd /root && make"`, my output is: `ls -l foo* -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Sep 27  2018 fool`. `Dockerfile` for `withmake`: `from i386/ubuntu:18.04 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make`. You can see if any different with your part, you may need to compare to see what happened to your situation.

Comment: One difference I noticed is that it appears as you are using a Linux NFS server.  I am using a MacOS NFS server.  I've posted additional details in the question.

Comment: I'm having this problem on my work laptop.  I'll try and reproduce it on my home machine.  I hope it's not a corporate malware issue.